# Consistent vertical spacing in cases environment with multirow cases

Tags: amsmath, unicode-math, cases, delimiters, vertical-spacing

I'm having trouble figuring out how to achieve some sort of consistency when I work with vertical spacing in `cases` environments where the cases themselves have multiple rows.

In the second version of the equation below, the `multlined` environment introduces too much space for the different cases. This can be adjusted by using e.g. `\\[-3ex]` and the like. While I'm not certain that there should be a need for it, the same method could be used to add extra spaces between the cases (`\\[3ex]`). But I'm pretty much just testing and trying to find something that doesn't look too bad.

Is there some way of giving this exercise a bit more structure and consistency? I want the rows of each case look like the belong together and the cases to look like they are distinct. Or am I just using a bad method of to reduce the amount space the equation takes up horisontally?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    \Delta(i, x; \symbf{p}, \symbf{p}')
    &= \begin{cases}
      \mathrm{e}^{1 / \alpha} {\Bigl(\frac{q_{\mathrm{i}}}{p_{\mathrm{h}}' + \delta}\Bigr)}^{1 - \alpha} \left(1 + (1 - \alpha) \frac{p_{\mathrm{h}}' - p_{\mathrm{h}}^{\mathrm{r}}}{q_{\mathrm{i}}}\right) - 1 & \text{if \(\nu = 1\), \(i = 1\)} \\
      \mathrm{e}^{1 / \alpha} {\Bigl(\frac{p_{\mathrm{h}} + \delta}{p_{\mathrm{h}}' + \delta}\Bigr)}^{1 - \alpha} \left(1 + (1 - \alpha) \frac{p_{\mathrm{h}}' - p_{\mathrm{h}}}{p_{\mathrm{h}} + \delta}\right) - 1 & \text{if \(\nu = 1\), \(i \neq 1\)} \\
      {\biggl({\Bigl(\frac{q_{\mathrm{i}}}{p_{\mathrm{h}}' + \delta}\Bigr)}^{1 - \alpha} \left(1 + (1 - \alpha) \frac{p_{\mathrm{h}}' - p_{\mathrm{h}}^{\mathrm{r}}}{q_{\mathrm{i}}}\right)\biggr)}^{1 / \alpha} - 1 & \text{if \(\nu \neq 1\), \(i = 1\)} \\
      {\biggl({\Bigl(\frac{p_{\mathrm{h}} + \delta}{p_{\mathrm{h}}' + \delta}\Bigr)}^{1 - \alpha} \left(1 + (1 - \alpha) \frac{p_{\mathrm{h}}' - p_{\mathrm{h}}}{p_{\mathrm{h}} + \delta}\right)\biggr)}^{1 / \alpha} - 1 & \text{if \(\nu \neq 1\), \(i \neq 1\)}
    \end{cases} \\
    &= \begin{cases}
      \begin{multlined}
        \mathrm{e}^{1 / \alpha} {\Bigl(\tfrac{q_{\mathrm{i}}}{p_{\mathrm{h}}' + \delta}\Bigr)}^{1 - \alpha} \\ \cdot \left(1 + (1 - \alpha) \tfrac{p_{\mathrm{h}}' - p_{\mathrm{h}}^{\mathrm{r}}}{q_{\mathrm{i}}}\right) - 1
      \end{multlined} & \text{if \(\nu = 1\), \(i = 1\)} \\
      \begin{multlined}
        \mathrm{e}^{1 / \alpha} {\Bigl(\tfrac{p_{\mathrm{h}} + \delta}{p_{\mathrm{h}}' + \delta}\Bigr)}^{1 - \alpha} \\ \cdot \left(1 + (1 - \alpha) \tfrac{p_{\mathrm{h}}' - p_{\mathrm{h}}}{p_{\mathrm{h}} + \delta}\right) - 1
      \end{multlined} & \text{if \(\nu = 1\), \(i \neq 1\)} \\
      \begin{multlined}
        \biggl({\Bigl(\tfrac{q_{\mathrm{i}}}{p_{\mathrm{h}}' + \delta}\Bigr)}^{1 - \alpha} \\ \hphantom{\biggl(} \cdot \left(1 + (1 - \alpha) \tfrac{p_{\mathrm{h}}' - p_{\mathrm{h}}^{\mathrm{r}}}{q_{\mathrm{i}}}\right)\biggr)^{1 / \alpha} - 1
      \end{multlined} & \text{if \(\nu \neq 1\), \(i = 1\)} \\
      \begin{multlined}
        \biggl({\Bigl(\tfrac{p_{\mathrm{h}} + \delta}{p_{\mathrm{h}}' + \delta}\Bigr)}^{1 - \alpha} \\ \hphantom{\biggl(} \cdot \left(1 + (1 - \alpha) \tfrac{p_{\mathrm{h}}' - p_{\mathrm{h}}}{p_{\mathrm{h}} + \delta}\right)\biggr)^{1 / \alpha} - 1
      \end{multlined} & \text{if \(\nu \neq 1\), \(i \neq 1\)}
    \end{cases}
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: Results]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or am I just using a bad method for reducing the amount space the equation takes up horisontally?

I can't see a good reason for using `multlined` here. To enforce uniform sizes of the tall round parentheses, don't go back and forth between `\Bigl`/`\Bigr` and `\left`/`\right`. Instead, use `\Bigl`/`\Bigr` throughout, and don't hesitate to switch the delimiter type, say, to square brackets for the outermost delimiters. In the screenshot posted below, notice how the space between rows 3 and 4 is the same as that between rows 1 and 2 (and, for that matter, between rows 2 and 3); that's not the case in the screenshot posted by the OP.

Separately, feel free to use a spacing modifier such as `\jot` to increase the vertical separation between rows. And, do please see fit to get rid of the needless code clutter caused by encasing the `\Bigl...\Bigr` and `\left...\right` constructs in curly braces.

I can't see a good reason for using `\mathrm` for the `h`, `i`, and `r` subscripts/superscripts either. For sure, the OP uses a "regular", i.e., *math-italic* `i` in the conditioning phrases. Anyway, if it's essential to use upright lettering for the `i`, `h`, and `r` terms, I'd use `\symup` rather than `\mathrm` as the OP appears to be using the `unicode-math` package.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}      % for 'cases' environment and '\jot' macro
\usepackage{unicode-math} % for '\symbf' command

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\Delta(i, x; \symbf{p}, \symbf{p}')
= \begin{cases}
\mathrm{e}^{1/\alpha} \Bigl(\frac{q_{i}}{p_{h}' + \delta}\Bigr)^{\!1-\alpha} 
   \Bigl(1 + (1-\alpha) \frac{p_{h}' - p_{h}^{r}}{q_{i}}\Bigr) - 1 
   & \text{if \(\nu = 1\), \(i = 1\)} \\[2\jot]
\mathrm{e}^{1/\alpha} \Bigl(\frac{p_{h} + \delta}{p_{h}' + \delta}\Bigr)^{\!1-\alpha} 
   \Bigl(1 + (1-\alpha) \frac{p_{h}' - p_{h}}{p_{h} + \delta}\Bigr) - 1 
   & \text{if \(\nu = 1\), \(i \neq 1\)} \\[2\jot]
\Bigr[\Bigl(\frac{q_{i}}{p_{h}' + \delta}\Bigr)^{\!1-\alpha} 
   \Bigl(1 + (1-\alpha) \frac{p_{h}' - p_{h}^{r}}{q_{i}}\Bigr)
   \Bigr]^{1/\alpha} \!- 1 
   & \text{if \(\nu \neq 1\), \(i = 1\)} \\[2\jot]
\Bigl[\Bigl(\frac{p_{h} + \delta}{p_{h}' + \delta}\Bigr)^{\!1-\alpha} 
   \Bigl(1 + (1-\alpha) \frac{p_{h}' - p_{h}}{p_{h} + \delta}\Bigr)
   \Bigr]^{1/\alpha} \!- 1 
   & \text{if \(\nu \neq 1\), \(i \neq 1\)}
\end{cases} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the many tips! Sorry for neglecting to include `unicode-math`... As for the math-italic i vs the roman letter, the former is a variable whereas the latter are labels. (This is me trying to follow [CMOS 12.36](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch12/psec036.html): "Abbreviations or words that serve as labels in subscripts or superscripts are usually set in roman type".

Comment: But while the tips are useful (and in this case sufficient), they don't address what to do if the cases _still_ are too long to fit in a single row. A first step would be having the left hand side on a separate row. But if that's not sufficient either then perhaps it is time to break the cases into separate rows.

Comment: @FredrikP - The subscripts `i` and `h` and the superscript `r` are *not* "abbreviations or words that serve as labels" in the sense of the CMOS excerpt you provided. If anything, they serve as "indexes".

Comment: @FredrikP - If you find it necessary to introduce a line break somewhere in the material to the left of the `&` dividers in a `cases` environment, I'd recommend you use `aligned[b]` environments, not `multlined` environments, and employ a fixed horizontal offset of, say, `\quad` or `\qquad` at the start of the continuation rows.

Comment: The subscript `i` here is an abbreviation of "insider", the subscript `h` of "homeowner", and the superscript `r` of "regulated". Am I misinterpreting the CMOS text?

Comment: Thanks for the `aligned[b]` tip!

Comment: @FredrikP - Ah, I was assuming that the letter `i` in the subscript position had the same meaning as the letter `ì` in `\(i = 1\)` or `\(i \ne 1\)` -- and hence should also be typeset the same way. If, to the contrary, the upright-i and italic-i letters have different meanings, you may want to choose a different letter for one of them...

Comment: The letter `i` in `\(i = 1\)` and `\(i \neq 1\)` is indeed distinct from the subscript `i`. Perhaps there is still room for notational improvements...

Answer (score 3):

With use of `\medmath` macro defined in the `nccmath` package (which reduce equation size for about 20 %) and `dcases` defined in the `mathtools` package you can get the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}  
\DeclareMathOperator{\e}{e}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{equation}\medmath{
\Delta(i, x; p, p')
= \begin{dcases}
\e^{1/\alpha} \Bigl(\frac{q_{i}}{p_{h}' + \delta}\Bigr)^{1-\alpha}
   \Bigl(1 + (1-\alpha) \frac{p_{h}' - p_{h}^{r}}{q_{i}}\Bigr) - 1
   & \text{if } \nu = 1,\; i = 1    \\
\e^{1/\alpha} \Bigl(\frac{p_{h} + \delta}{p_{h}' + \delta}\Bigr)^{1-\alpha}
   \Bigl(1 + (1-\alpha) \frac{p_{h}' - p_{h}}{p_{h} + \delta}\Bigr) - 1
   & \text{if } \nu = 1,\; i \neq 1 \\
\biggl[\Bigl(\frac{q_{i}}{p_{h}' + \delta}\Bigr)^{1-\alpha}
   \Bigl(1 + (1-\alpha) \frac{p_{h}' - p_{h}^{r}}{q_{i}}\Bigr)
    \biggr]^{1/\alpha} - 1
   & \text{if } \nu \neq 1,\; i = 1  \\
\biggl[\Bigl(\frac{p_{h} + \delta}{p_{h}' + \delta}\Bigr)^{1-\alpha}
   \Bigl(1 + (1-\alpha) \frac{p_{h}' - p_{h}}{p_{h} + \delta}\Bigr)
    \biggr]^{1/\alpha} - 1
   & \text{if } \nu \neq 1\), \(\; i \neq 1 
\end{dcases}}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Since you're using a `dcases` environment, you may also want to use `\bigg[lr]` instead of `\Big[lr]`.

Comment: @Mico, good point. Now they looks a bit to small. I will enlarge them ASAP